# Will fresh bell peppers give stew a red colour?

Tags: color, pepper

I know ground paprika from red bell peppers does give a red colour to a stew.  Just wondering if the bell peppers are fresh cuts and not ground, will it give the stew a red colour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally no. Paprika and the like are dried and powdered. You will likely get some red coloration if you puree your fresh red peppers before adding to your stew. Absent that step, the red remains mostly in the pepper chunks.